# Why PHP repeat the pages in PDF?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I have a PDF with FPDF. This PDF is generating with some MySQL querys. The first query count the values of the table for repeat, the second get values for PDF's header, the third query get the referees with match on a day of game(the referees are get from the last query), the fourth query is execute if the referee has a match and get the match he has and print it into the PDF.
If the referee has only one match all it's ok but if he has more of one PHP prints such pages than match he has and all the pages has all the match for the referee. I want to do it without pages repeat.
This is the code I have.

```
$jornada=$_GET['jornada'];
include"fpdf.php";
include"conexion.php";
class PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header(){
        global $sede, $localidad, $apellidos, $nombre;
        $this->Image('images/logo.jpg', 10, 5, 20);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
        $this->Cell(180);
        $this->Cell(20, 0, utf8_decode('Designaciones árbitro'), 'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
        $this->Cell(180);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
        $this->Cell(20, 0, utf8_decode('Nombre: ('.$sede."".$localidad.") ".$apellidos.', '.$nombre), 'C');
        $this->Ln(15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 22);
        $this->Cell(0,0,'',1);
        $this->Ln(1);
    }
    function Footer(){
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}
function fullUpper($localidad){
    return strtr(strtoupper($localidad), array(
      "à" => "À",
      "è" => "È",
      "ì" => "Ì",
      "ò" => "Ò",
      "ù" => "Ù",
      "á" => "Á",
      "é" => "É",
      "í" => "Í",
      "ó" => "Ó",
      "ú" => "Ú",
      "â" => "Â",
      "ê" => "Ê",
      "î" => "Î",
      "ô" => "Ô",
      "û" => "Û",
      "ç" => "Ç",
    ));
} 
$pdf=new PDF('L','mm','A4');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$sql=new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
$sql->set_charset("latin1");
if($sql->connect_error){
    echo "Error no ".$sql->connect_errno.": ".$sql->connect_error;
}
$r=$sql->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL");
while($row11=$r->fetch_array()){
    $r1=$sql->query("SELECT Apellidos, Licencia FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL");
    while($row12=$r1->fetch_array()){
        $apellidos=$row12["Apellidos"];
        $licencia=$row12["Licencia"];
        $res=$sql->query("SELECT DISTINCT Apellidos, P1.EquipoA AS 'a1',P2.EquipoA AS 'a2',P3.EquipoA AS 'a3',P4.EquipoA AS 'a4',P5.EquipoA AS 'a5',P6.EquipoA AS 'a6', EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Nombre ArbNom, LOCALIDAD.Nombre LocNom, SEDE.Codigo_sede FROM EQUIPO_ARBITRAL
            INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Cod_localidad=LOCALIDAD.Codigo_localidad INNER JOIN SEDE ON LOCALIDAD.Codigo_sede=SEDE.Codigo_sede
            LEFT JOIN PARTIDO P1 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P1.ArbPrin LEFT JOIN PARTIDO P2 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P2.ArbAux
            LEFT JOIN PARTIDO P3 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P3.Anotador LEFT JOIN PARTIDO P4 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P4.Crono
            LEFT JOIN PARTIDO P5 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P5.Op24 LEFT JOIN PARTIDO P6 ON EQUIPO_ARBITRAL.Codigo_arbitro=P6.Coche
            WHERE Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' AND Licencia='$licencia'
            AND (P1.Jornada=$jornada OR P2.Jornada=$jornada OR P3.Jornada=$jornada OR P4.Jornada=$jornada OR P5.Jornada=$jornada OR P6.Jornada=$jornada)");
        while($row=$res->fetch_array()){
            $sede=$row["Codigo_sede"];
            $localidad=$row["LocNom"];
            $apellidos=$row["Apellidos"];
            $nombre=$row["ArbNom"];
            $a1=$row["a1"];
            $a2=$row["a2"];
            $a3=$row["a3"];
            $a4=$row["a4"];
            $a5=$row["a5"];
            $a6=$row["a6"];
            switch($localidad){
                case 'Alhaurín de la Torre': 
                    $localidad='ALT';
                break;
                case 'Alhaurín el Grande':
                    $localidad='ALG';
                break;
                case 'Málaga':
                    $sede='';
                break;
            }
            $localidad=substr($localidad, 0, 4);
            $localidad=fullUpper($localidad);
            if($a1!=null or $a2!=null or $a3!=null or $a4!=null or $a5!=null or $a6!=null){
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $mysqli=new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
                $mysqli->set_charset("latin1");
                if($mysqli->connect_error){
                    echo "Error no ".$mysqli->connect_errno.": ".$mysqli->connect_error;
                }
                $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT E1.Nombre EquipoA, E2.Nombre EquipoB, DATE_FORMAT(Fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'Fecha', TIME_FORMAT(Hora, '%H:%i') AS 'Hora', Abreviatura, Tipo, LOCALIDAD.Nombre Localidad, PA.Nombre Pista, PA.Codigo_pabellon, 
                CONCAT(A1.Licencia, ' ', A1.Apellidos,', ', A1.Nombre) ArbPrin, CONCAT(A2.Licencia, ' ', A2.Apellidos,', ', A2.Nombre) ArbAux, CONCAT(A3.Licencia, ' ', A3.Apellidos,', ', A3.Nombre) Anotador, CONCAT(A4.Licencia, ' ', A4.Apellidos,', ', A4.Nombre) Crono, CONCAT(A5.Licencia, ' ', A5.Apellidos,', ', A5.Nombre) Op24, CONCAT(A6.Licencia, ' ', A6.Apellidos,', ', A6.Nombre) Coche
                FROM PARTIDO P INNER JOIN EQUIPO E1 ON P.EquipoA=E1.Codigo_equipo 
                INNER JOIN EQUIPO E2 ON P.EquipoB=E2.Codigo_equipo 
                INNER JOIN PABELLON PA ON P.Codigo_pabellon=PA.Codigo_pabellon 
                INNER JOIN CATEGORIA ON P.Codigo_categoria=CATEGORIA.Codigo_categoria
                INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD ON  PA.Codigo_localidad=LOCALIDAD.Codigo_localidad
                INNER JOIN SEDE ON LOCALIDAD.Codigo_sede=SEDE.Codigo_sede
                LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A1 ON A1.Codigo_arbitro=P.ArbPrin
                LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A2 ON A2.Codigo_arbitro=P.ArbAux
                LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A3 ON A3.Codigo_arbitro=P.Anotador
                LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A4 ON A4.Codigo_arbitro=P.Crono
                LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A5 ON A5.Codigo_arbitro=P.Op24
                LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A6 ON A6.Codigo_arbitro=P.Coche
                WHERE Jornada=$jornada AND (A1.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR A2.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' 
                OR A3.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR A4.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR
                A5.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR A6.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%')
                ORDER BY Fecha, Hora");
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
                $pdf->Cell(165);
                $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Principal');
                $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Anotador');
                $pdf->Ln(5);
                $pdf->Cell(165);
                $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Auxiliar');
                $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Cronometrador');
                $pdf->Ln(5);
                $pdf->Cell(10);
                $pdf->Cell(10,10,'Encuentro');
                $pdf->Cell(40);
                $pdf->Cell(25,10, 'Fecha');
                $pdf->Cell(15,10, 'Hora');
                $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Categoria');
                $pdf->Cell(25,10, 'Compet.');
                $pdf->Cell(10);
                $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Coche');
                $pdf->Cell(60,10, 'Operador 24"');
                $pdf->Ln(10);
                $pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1);
                $pdf->Ln(1);
                $pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1);
                $pdf->Ln(1);
                while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
                    $pdf->Cell(60,10,utf8_decode(substr($row["EquipoA"], 0, 40)));
                    $pdf->Cell(25,10,$row["Fecha"]);
                    $pdf->Cell(15,10,$row["Hora"]);
                    $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Abreviatura"]);
                    $pdf->Cell(18,10,$row["Tipo"]);
                    $pdf->Cell(65,10,utf8_decode($row["ArbPrin"]));
                    $pdf->Cell(3);
                    $pdf->Cell(65,10,utf8_decode($row["Anotador"]));
                    $pdf->Ln(5);
                    $pdf->Cell(60,10,utf8_decode(substr($row["EquipoB"], 0, 40)));
                    $pdf->Cell(88);
                    $pdf->Cell(60,10,utf8_decode($row["ArbAux"]));
                    $pdf->Cell(8);
                    $pdf->Cell(60,10,utf8_decode($row["Crono"]));
                    $pdf->Ln(5);
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
                    $pdf->Cell(20,10,'Localidad: ');
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
                    $pdf->Cell(30,10,utf8_decode($row["Localidad"]));
                    $pdf->Cell(25);
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
                    $pdf->Cell(12,10,'Pista: ');
                    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
                    $pdf->Cell(30,10,utf8_decode($row["Pista"]));
                    $pdf->Cell(31);
                    $pdf->Cell(60,10,utf8_decode($row["Coche"]));
                    $pdf->Cell(8);
                    $pdf->Cell(60,10,utf8_decode($row["Op24"]));
                    $pdf->Ln(7);
                    $pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1);
                    $pdf->Ln(1);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
mysqli_close($mysqli);
mysqli_close($sql);
```

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: Date and time should be one column

Comment: I think the problem isn't that because the date and time aren't relevant for the print

Comment: I know, but still... Anyway, if it was me I'd simplify the problem down a bit. Let's forget all about the php stuff and just focus on returning the desired result set. To do that, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - all simplified, if necessary.

Comment: I try it on MySQL Workbench and all it's OK. The problem is in one PHP loop